# First job! I need some DE 4 tax form help

Tags: united-states, california, state-income-tax

I just got my first paying job and they need me to fill out the DE 4 for California income tax.

And to be honest it's a little confusing.

http://www.edd.ca.gov/pdf_pub_ctr/de4.pdf

Firstly because I'm a dependent on my parents taxes should I still bubble myself in as Single for the "Filing Status Withholding Allowances" section?

Secondly, in Worksheet A on page 3 should I count allowances for myself as 1 (even though I'm a dependent)?

For Section B question 1: what the heck does "itemized deductions for California taxes" even mean? I know what itemized deductions are but I'm a bit confused as to what they want in this case...

For Section B question 2: should I enter $3992 for single even if I'm a dependent?

Thanks for your help! I really do appreciate it

Comment: What makes you think you're their dependent?